# Cordova 4.0.0 is installing 3.6.4

Tags: cordova, npm, version

I have updated to Cordova 4.0.0.
Whenever I run `cordova platform add android` it fetches 3.6.4 Cordova library. What am I missing?

```
$ cordova -v
4.0.0
$ cordova platform add android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.4.tgz
```

*EDIT:* I've cleared any npm cache.

Comment: This is correct. This is not Cordova 4.0, it's Cordova-CLI 4.0 Read here: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html

Comment: Hmmm.. Ok, little bit confusing. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Miquel.....Did you solve your problem. I am now facing this problem. I am getting this error message npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
Unable to fetch platform android: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND. If you overcome from this situation, I am looking for your way out(solution).

Comment: Hi @Banshidhari, as noted by Dawson this is not an error, it is correct: 4.0 it's Cordova-CLI and 3.6.4 is cordova version (read the link from Dawson)

Comment: Hi @Miquel I get the message Unable to fetch platform android: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND. May I know what is this meaning unable to fetch platform android

Comment: @Banshidhari, sorry I don't know. Maybe [Google knows](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable+to+fetch+platform+android%3A+Error%3A+tunneling+socket+could+not+be+established%2C+cause%3Dgetaddrinfo+ENOTFOUND) or maybe you could open a new question or post your question in cordova forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are now two different questions here.

Q #1 is the OP's question, essentially "Why do I see cordova 3.6.4 being downloaded when I have installed cordova 4.0.0 ?"

This was well answered by Dawson above [Cordova 4.0.0 is installing 3.6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427503/cordova-4-0-0-is-installing-3-6-4#comment41500939_26427503) -- the `cordova` command-line program is at version 4.0.0 but the cordova library is at version 3.6.4, so this is expected (although confusing) behavior.

Q #2 is @Banshidhari 's question [Cordova 4.0.0 is installing 3.6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427503/cordova-4-0-0-is-installing-3-6-4#comment42633503_26427503) which is essentially "How can I solve getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND during `npm install`"

This is a symptom of a local networking issue, where `node`'s HTTP client library `request` is not able to find the address of `registry.npmjs.org`.  Usually this can be resolved by making sure that your `http_proxy` variable is set correctly:

`npm config set http_proxy http://path.to.proxy:port`

However if you are still having problems, Banshidhari, please open an new question or open an issue on https://github.com/npm/npm/issues